# window/panel always seems to be 3 chars width

Tags: c++, terminal, ncurses

I am trying to create a ncursesw program using c++ with a moving window. but my window seems to always be 3 chars in with. I have no clue what I am doing wrong even with getmaxyx I get the right size of the window.

here is my code:

```
#ifndef MAIN_CPP
#define MAIN_CPP

#include <iostream>
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>
#include <panel.h>

using namespace std;

void quit();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Init Curses ----------
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  WINDOW* win = initscr();
  atexit(quit);
  curs_set(0);
  start_color();
  clear();
  noecho();
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, true);

  // Create window / panel
  WINDOW* win2 = newwin(9, 18, 0, 0);
  PANEL* pan2 = new_panel(win2);

  waddstr(win, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

  waddstr(win2, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

  box(win2, 0, 0);

  update_panels();
  doupdate();

  getch();

  return 0;
}

void quit() {
  endwin();
}

#endif
```

I compile using:

```
g++ -o wintest main.cpp -lncursesw -lpanel
```

and my output alsways looks like this:
[image: output]

The window and panel only take up a width of 3 the waddstr clearly writes 18 chars and breaks to another like after the 18 char and the box also tries to output the correct size but there is only the first 3 columns visible. (this is indicated by the output of the uppercase chars being visible on the stdwin (var name win) and the lower case chars beginning in the second line at the letter s (behind the box) which is the 19 char in the output.)

Answer (score 1):

That's from one window/refresh overwriting another.  Here's a debug-trace (omitting some detail for the `keypad`, to keep it short):

```
TRACING NCURSES version 6.3.20221029 (tracelevel=0x24)
- TRACE_UPDATE (4)
- TRACE_CALLS (32)
called {initscr()
_nc_alloc_screen_sp screen1
your terminal name is screen.xterm-new
using 2048 for getstr limit
duplicate /usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo
duplicate /usr/share/terminfo
duplicate /usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo
not found /users/tom/.terminfo
_nc_next_db 1 /usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo
_nc_setup_tinfo returns 1
screen size: terminfo lines = 24 columns = 80
SYS screen size: environment LINES = 40 COLUMNS = 80
screen size: environment LINES = 24
screen size is 24x80
TABSIZE = 8
created SP screen1
screen size: terminfo lines = 24 columns = 80
SYS screen size: environment LINES = 40 COLUMNS = 80
screen size: environment LINES = 24
screen size is 24x80
TABSIZE = 8
create :screen screen.xterm-new 24x80
initializing ACS map
READ acs_chars "``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~"
DIFF acs_chars "+>,<-^.v0#A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+Q-R-T+U+V+W+X|Y|``aaffggh#iijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~"
2 REPEATS OF _nc_unicode_locale(UTF-8) ->1
initializing WIDE-ACS map (Unicode is active)
_nc_get_locale "en_US.UTF-8"
legacy-coding 0
creating newscr
create :window newscr
creating curscr
create :window curscr
creating stdscr
create :window stdscr
_nc_tiparm: format is null
CatchIfDefault - will catch SIGINT
CatchIfDefault - will catch SIGTERM
CatchIfDefault - will catch SIGWINCH
return }stdscr
called {curs_set(screen1,0)
return }1
called {start_color(screen1)
started color: COLORS = 8, COLOR_PAIRS = 64
return }0
called {clear()
return }0
called {noecho(screen1)
return }0
called {cbreak(screen1)
return }0
called {keypad(stdscr,1)
return }0
called {newwin(screen1, 9,18,0,0)
create :window window0
return }window0
called {new_panel(window0)
create :root_panel panel0
create :user_ptr user_ptr0
create :new_panel panel1
create :user_ptr user_ptr1
--> show_panel "user_ptr1"
<lt1> b="user_ptr0" t="user_ptr0"
pan id="user_ptr1"
stk id="user_ptr0" b=-- a=-- y=0 x=0
<lt9> b="user_ptr0" t="user_ptr1"
pan id="user_ptr1"
stk id="user_ptr0" b=-- a="user_ptr1" y=0 x=0
stk id="user_ptr1" b="user_ptr0" a=-- y=0 x=0
return }panel1
RUN of waddnstr()s: stdscr, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
RUN of waddnstr()s: window0, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
called {box(window0,{000},{000})
using {ACS_VLINE}, {ACS_VLINE}, {ACS_HLINE}, {ACS_HLINE}, {ACS_ULCORNER}, {ACS_URCORNER}, {ACS_LLCORNER}, {ACS_LRCORNER}
return }0
called {update_panels(screen1)
--> update_panels
wnoutrefresh id="user_ptr0" b=-- a="user_ptr1" y=0 x=0
...win[ 0]   0 79 ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '
...win[ 1]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[ 2]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[ 3]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[ 4]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[ 5]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[ 6]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[ 7]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[ 8]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[ 9]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[10]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[11]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[12]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[13]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[14]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[15]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[16]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[17]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[18]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[19]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[20]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[21]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[22]   0 79 ='                           '
...win[23]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[ 0]   0 79 ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '
newscr[ 1]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[ 2]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[ 3]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[ 4]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[ 5]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[ 6]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[ 7]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[ 8]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[ 9]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[10]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[11]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[12]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[13]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[14]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[15]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[16]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[17]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[18]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[19]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[20]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[21]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[22]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[23]   0 79 ='                           '
wnoutrefresh id="user_ptr1" b="user_ptr0" a=-- y=0 x=0
...win[ 0]   0 17 ='lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqk'
attrs1[ 0]        ='444444444444444444'
...win[ 1]   0 17 ='xtuvwxyz         x'
attrs1[ 1]        ='4                4'
...win[ 2]   0 17 ='x                x'
attrs1[ 2]        ='4                4'
...win[ 3]   0 17 ='x                x'
attrs1[ 3]        ='4                4'
...win[ 4]   0 17 ='x                x'
attrs1[ 4]        ='4                4'
...win[ 5]   0 17 ='x                x'
attrs1[ 5]        ='4                4'
...win[ 6]   0 17 ='x                x'
attrs1[ 6]        ='4                4'
...win[ 7]   0 17 ='x                x'
attrs1[ 7]        ='4                4'
...win[ 8]   0 17 ='mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj'
attrs1[ 8]        ='444444444444444444'
newscr[ 0]   0 79 ='lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqkSTUVWXYZ '
attrs1[ 0]        ='444444444444444444         '
newscr[ 1]   0 79 ='xtuvwxyz         x         '
attrs1[ 1]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 2]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 2]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 3]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 3]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 4]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 4]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 5]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 5]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 6]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 6]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 7]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 7]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 8]   0 79 ='mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj         '
attrs1[ 8]        ='444444444444444444         '
newscr[ 9]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[10]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[11]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[12]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[13]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[14]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[15]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[16]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[17]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[18]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[19]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[20]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[21]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[22]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[23]   0 79 ='                           '
return }
called {_nc_tinfo:doupdate(screen1)
curscr[ 0]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[ 1]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[ 2]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[ 3]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[ 4]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[ 5]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[ 6]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[ 7]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[ 8]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[ 9]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[10]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[11]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[12]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[13]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[14]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[15]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[16]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[17]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[18]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[19]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[20]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[21]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[22]   0 79 ='  '
curscr[23]   0 79 ='  '
newscr[ 0]   0 79 ='lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqkSTUVWXYZ '
attrs1[ 0]        ='444444444444444444         '
newscr[ 1]   0 79 ='xtuvwxyz         x         '
attrs1[ 1]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 2]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 2]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 3]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 3]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 4]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 4]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 5]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 5]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 6]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 6]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 7]   0 79 ='x                x         '
attrs1[ 7]        ='4                4         '
newscr[ 8]   0 79 ='mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj         '
attrs1[ 8]        ='444444444444444444         '
newscr[ 9]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[10]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[11]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[12]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[13]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[14]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[15]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[16]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[17]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[18]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[19]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[20]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[21]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[22]   0 79 ='                           '
newscr[23]   0 79 ='                           '
ClearScreen() called
screen cleared
updating screen from scratch
return }0
called {wgetch(stdscr)
wgetch returning : 012
return }10
called {endwin(screen1)
return }0
```

Each of these does a refresh, either explicitly or as a side-effect:

```cpp
  update_panels();
  doupdate();

  getch();
```

Comment: Hi, so I had finally time to test it, and if I remove either one of them (doupdate or update_panels) I only get the main screen output the win2 wont display at all

Comment: With curses, when you refresh a window which overlaps with other windows, you'll see the refreshed window - and it'll be "in front" of the other windows.  That's consistent with the debug trace.  See `wnoutrefresh`.

Comment: Ah ok I've tried wrefresh for each win in order and now I works. can you add this code to your answer so I can mark it as correct. thanks btw